# C# Entity Framework select self referencing many to many

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to build a generic dropdownlist view model that can have many drop down lists inside it.

When I use Entity Framework to select the dropdownlist vm and inside it select another list of dropdownlist vm I get an error. However if I change my code to have 2 vms instead of using 1 generic 1 everything works fine. I am trying to avoid extra classes and keep the same viewmodels consistent across all my projects.

Error:

> DropDownSelect' appears in two structurally incompatible
>   initializations within a single LINQ to Entities query. A type can be
>   initialized in two places in the same query, but only if the same
>   properties are set in both places and those properties are set in the
>   same order.

ViewModel:

```
public class DropDownSelect
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<DropDownSelect> Next { get; set; }

    public DropDownSelect()
    {
        Next = new List<DropDownSelect>();
    }
}
```

Linq:

```
public static async Task<List<DropDownSelect>> SelectReportDropDown(bool isPpm, int companyId = 0)
{
    using (var context = ContextFactory.getLiveConnection())
    {
        return await context.Companies.Select(c => new DropDownSelect()
        {
            Id = c.ID,
            Name = c.Name,
            Next = c.Reports.Select(p => new DropDownSelect()
            {
                Id = p.ProjectId,
                Name = p.Name,
            }).ToList()
        }).ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: That is not the same question or answer. I do not agree with the duplicate. Maybe you made a mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As clear in the error message, Entity Framework does not like the fact that you are using the same class (i.e., `DropDownSelect`) in two places inside the query and each time you are setting different properties. That is, in the first time, you are setting `Id`, `Name`, and `Next`, but the second time your are setting `Id` and `Name` only.

To fix this, use an [anonymous type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) in the query, and later convert it to `DropDownSelect` like this:

```
public static async Task<List<DropDownSelect>> SelectReportDropDown(bool isPpm, int companyId = 0)
{
    using (var context = ContextFactory.getLiveConnection())
    {
        var result = await context.Companies.Select(c => new // this is an anonymous type
        {
            Id = c.ID,
            Name = c.Name,
            Next = c.Reports.Select(p => new DropDownSelect //DropDownSelect is now used in only one place in the query
            {
                Id = p.ProjectId,
                Name = p.Name,
            }).ToList()
        }).ToListAsync();

        return result.Select(x => new DropDownSelect
        {
            Id = x.Id,
            Name = x.Name,
            Next = x.Next
        }).ToList();


    }
}
```

Comment: Can i just return the anonymous type through web api and skip the mapping part? This works but the code is duplicated especially if I am going more than 2 levels.

Comment: I don't think you can do that.

Comment: But in terms of performance, the mapping is going to take a relatively negligible time (compared to a database query).

Comment: Ok if I return an object it works and it maps to json perfectly. I was getting an error initially because I was trying to return a List<object>

Comment: @MIKE, I am not sure I understand

Comment: public static async Task<object> SelectReportDropDown(bool isPpm, int companyId = 0)

everything works perfectly I dont need to map the web api handles it.

Comment: I see, but what about the client? what type does the client expect to receive?

Comment: It is javascript so it shouldn't matter what type